# how to make round buttons like the iOS 7 lock screen

Tags: ios7, uikit

Is there a predefined widget to make have round buttons in iOS7 like with the lock screen? I've been looking around at UIButton but I couldn't find anything. So their they're not UIButtons, or I'm not seeing it, or they just don't exist and I have to make my own custom buttons.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Link the framework in build steps then

Import:

```
#import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h
```

Code:

```
self.fiveButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.fiveButton.bounds.size.width/2.0;
self.fiveButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
self.fiveButton.layer.borderColor = self.fiveButton.titleLabel.textColor.CGColor;
self.fiveButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:35];
```

This isn't *exactly* right: I don't have the label moved up (there are inserts for that) and I haven't figured out the exact font, but it's almost there.

https://github.com/langford/RoundButtonDemo/blob/master/screenshot.png

git@github.com:langford/RoundButtonDemo.git

Comment: Ah ok. I figured I'd have to make a custom button. I just didn't know if there was a pre-made widget or something I had missed. Thanks

Comment: ok it's working but the interaction with original square area outside the circle  is still working. do u have any solution for that ??????