# how to make the add and edit button like in the alarm application

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to make two button (add and delete) in the top of the view in my application just like the alarm clock.

how can i put like these buttons can anyone help me?

many thanks,

Comment: Drag two buttons from the Widget Pallette (forgot what it's called) on the bottom left corner. Then apply a rounded borded to the buttons with the appropriate colour strokes. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497860/how-to-make-round-buttons-like-the-ios-7-lock-screen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Initiate UIBarButtons in ViewDidLoad method

  ```
  UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addButtonTapped:)];

  UIBarButtonItem *editButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(editButtonTapped:)];
  ```
- Place them in navigationBar as NavigationItem

  ```
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButton;
  ```
- If you want to use two buttons on same side of NavigationBar use

  ```
  [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:editButton,addButton, nil]];
  ```

Answer (score -1):

These are called `UIBarButtonItem`s and you need to instantiate them and add to your navigationItem as follows in your viewDidLoad method of your view controller.

> self.navgiationItem.leftBarButtonItem = yourButtonInstance;

P.S. if you please ask your question with more detail like supporting it with screen shots, etc would be more helpful for answer.

This [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721169/adding-a-uibarbuttonitem-programmatically-to-uinavigationbar) is exactly what you need.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to add one in Navigation bar

```
-(void)setNavigationBarRightButton
{
            UIButton *rightButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 26)];
        [rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"setting.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rightButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:TRUE];
        [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickrighttButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        UIBarButtonItem *barBackItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
       // self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barBackItem;




}

- (void)onClickrighttButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"right button");


}
```

and in viewdidload

```
[self setNavigationBarRightButton];
```

You can add any image you like

Comment: I don't know why down voted but anyways it will gonna help someone else